# Forward RDP port on WinXP router to computer in internal (NATted) network

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, routing

So I have Windows XP serving as a router (two NICs - one internal, one external) NATting internal network with access to the internet (through external NIC). This external NIC has publicly accessible IP and RDP service running. This RDP service is accessible from the internet.

Then I have a computer in the internal network which I need to be able to reach through RDP from the internet (i.e. the external network).

I ve installed PassPort and set-up a rule to forward some free port on the WinXP router to RDP ports on the computer in the internal network. However as you can guess it does not work.

Any ideas how to make this work? I am not sure if PassPort itself works, but online web service reports that my port to be redirected to RDP is open. I would guess the problem is in routing because of the NAT, but I am not sure how to test (and fix) that. The bottom line is that I cannot connect externally through RDP to the internal network computer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it is possible to achieve the result by netsh command (available in XP from some SP I believe).

`netsh int ipv6 install
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=x listenaddress=y connectport=z connectaddress=zz`

This will forward port x on ip y to port z on ip zz. Hope this helps someone.